# Ubuntu web browsers doesn't show call back that came with error 500

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web-development, webbrowser-app

I'm a software developer. I have the problem that my web browsers (chrome, firefox, firefox developers...) stopped show me error 500 call backs. Doesn't appear on my developer tools xhr network calls.
My teammates in the same page, with the same web browsers (in windows) have the answer (error 500) but, I don't. Like not even the call is happening.
I always worked like this, and has to be something with ubuntu, because all the web browsers are doing the same.
Someone knows or have an idea of some configuration that could be making web browsers work like that?
I do back end and front end, and can't work like this. I need to see when back end is not working well

(please, I don't want to go back to windows)

Thanks in advance!

PS: I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS up to date (I don't know when this started, but has to be with latest updates)

Comment: There’s an insufficient amount of information here and an inconsistent use of words. By “explorers” do you mean *browsers*? As for the 500 error, is this a project that runs locally or one that operates on a different machine? If you carefully explain the development setup, it may be possible to identify the issue you’re facing.

Comment: Yes, I mean browsers... and the back end is on a server, in different machine.